# Hybris checkout process ending by prevention of order placement

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

Hybris 6.2, storefront accelerator :>>>

After completion summary step i cannot place order in my local as it showing there is problem with product,,... Please Contect to support dept.

Is this problem comes from configuration in my impex or something else.. Please suggest

Comment: Which version? Which accelerator? May your product hasn't got stock.

Comment: Also please add what exactly is the problem. Any exceptions ?

Comment: I solve this by : product does not have a tax class therefore tax is not calculated @nikita_pavlenko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you receive following error:

> We are sorry but your transaction could not be completed at this time;
>   please try again later or contact customer service at 555-555-5555

The problem may be related to following:

- Your product does not have a tax class therefore tax is not calculated and you have this error
- Payment for the order has not been authorized
- Your cart has not been calculated

It is 99% that you forgot to set TaxClass to the product.

Can you please share your impex?

Comment: Big Thank You for support, it works for me. You are right product tax is a big problem, Can you please explain how to configure my own tax in Hybris.